# Rails mailer error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer

Controller

```
  def mail_test
    @user = User.all.first
    @course = Course.all.first
    examplemailer.student_reminder(@user, @course).deliver
    redirect_to '/'

  end
```

Mailer controller

```
  def student_reminder(user, course)
    @user = user
    @course = course
    @url = 'http://www.google.com'
    mail to: @user.email, subject: "Good Job!"
  end
```

Here, I need to use <%=@user.name%> and <%= @course.title%>.

However, that code doesn't work, ending in the error

ArgumentError in Rails::MailersController#preview
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

at

```
 def student_reminder(user, course)
```

I think I have proper number of arguments (user and course)

Comment: The method says MailerController#preview. Do you have any calls to the preview method, or the source code of it?

Comment: Thank you for your help, fdisk. I didn't know that i have to add argument in the mailer_preview.rb file. It's now working. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above, the error was in the `MailerController#preview` method.